# Can a time-varying magnetic field pass a metal sheet?

Tags: current-transformer, magnetic-flux

I'm using CT (Current Transformer) to measure the current flowing on the power line. The frequency of the current is 13.56 MHz. CT appeared to be metal-shielded (This metal case of CT may be to be grounded).

CT has a toroidal shape and the power line under the measurement passes through the center hole of the CT, so azimuthal magnetic field around the power line induces EMF (ElectroMotive Force) on the coil inside the CT. This EMF is measured so the current on the power line is measured. This is the basic story of how CT works.

If the current frequency is low like 10 Hz, then I fully accept that CT really works. But I'm now confused at a high-frequency operation. The current is the source of the magnetic field and when the current oscillates, there is not only the magnetic field but also the electric field. The combined field is what we call an EM (ElectroMagnetic) wave. My frequency is 13.56 MHz which is a rather high-frequency, so the power line should play as an EM wave emitting antenna. EM wave generated from the power line propagates to CT first. However, CT has a rather thick metal case (much thicker than the skin depth at this frequency) so EM wave will be reflected from it. It means the magnetic field as a part of the EM wave fails to reach the coil inside the CT so CT should not work! **I think the only way for CT to work is that the magnetic field alone pass through the metal so they get in touch with the coil. But..Is it really possible? The time-varying magnetic field can exist alone without the electric field?**

Of course, there is a number of commercial CT in the same type which work well even for higher frequency. Could you please give me some idea of breaking this confusion?

Comment: 13MHz sounds very high for a conventional CT. If it says '13MHz' on the packet, then you can assume they have thought of the metal case issue, and split the case so it doesn't form a shorted turn, it shouldn't anyway, regardless of the operating frequency. If it doesn't say '13MHz' on the packet, what frequency range *is* the core rated to work over? I wouldn't use a CT at 13MHz, the frequency is high enough to use an air-core Rogowski coil, a cousin of the CT, but with voltage rather than current output. Link to a specification for the CT you have in mind.

Comment: Hello. My CT is from Pearson Electronics and I believe it can be operated up to 20 MHz, according to CT specification. The engineer said it is okay to use my frequency. Even though it is confirmed that I can use this, I would like to know how it operates. At 13.56 MHz, I think B field should be treated as a part of an EM wave, but..How 13.56MHz EM wave penetrates CT? CT has a metal case so I don't see a way that EM passes into CT. Could you give me some comments about it?

Comment: No, the frequency is not high enough to meaningfully regard this as an EM wave. The wavelength is 22 metres and your CT will be tiny in comparison. Provide a link to your CT.

Comment: http://pearsonelectronics.com/pdf/5046.pdf is the link of my CT. anyway...13.56 MHz is not high enough to be considered as an EM wave? Hm...could you tell me why? And could you give me some details for a part of your original comments "If it says '13MHz' on the packet, then you can assume they have thought of the metal case issue, and split the case so it doesn't form a shorted turn, it shouldn't anyway, regardless of the operating frequency." What does "split the case so it doesn't form a shorted turn, it shouldn't anyway, regardless of the operating frequency" mean?

Comment: it says 20MHz, use it.

Comment: A loop of metal around a wire will have a current induced in it running parallel to the wire, so any current induced in the casing will flow through the hole and return around the outside of the case. I am guessing there will be a break in the shielding along this path for optimal coupling but it should not be necessary except for extremely high currents or GHz frequencies.

Comment: If it's metal shielded, the shielding will be split so that it does not form a shorted turn, it could not work otherwise. If you want to think what that means, wind one shorted turn onto the core. Now work out where you have to cut it, to open the short circuit. That's where the metal casing will be split so it doesn't form a shorted turn, while it still provides electrostatic screening.

Comment: Something is wrong here: no *power* line system will be operating at 13.56 MHz. But that is the frequency for MiFare etc RFID cards.

Comment: @DonggyuJang you misunderstand me. Wavelength is much, much bigger than the size of the CT therefore considerations about electric fields are not required. I wish the link gave more detail but it looks genuine.

Answer (score 1):

The time-varying field around an AC conductor wire is in the circumferential
direction.   So, it induces current in metal that is perpendicular to that
circumferential direction, i.e. in the radial/Z axis plane.   The current
transformer ought to have no such metal in its shield 'container'.

With a sufficiently low burden resistor, AC performance of transformers can
easily be quite good; that burden resistor and its secondary current
act against the B field penetrating the core, so magnetic core losses
are kept small (because internal B field excursion is small).

As for 'electric field', a good conductor can get quite high induced
current from nearby AC wires, but a good conductor completely blocks
electric field very well: that's why electromagnetic waves (light) 
reflect well from the thin aluminum layer of a common mirror.

Magnetic field does not 'pass through' anything, it is not a flow
of some material.   The field lines are an abstraction for visualization
purposes, not trajectories of particles that can ... bounce.

Answer (score 0):

It is the losses in the core at high frequency that will make the CT not work at all.  Refer to [Eddy current losses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current).

Measuring large 14 MHz currents is not trivial and you will you will need a well designed axial current shunt, CT or transducer.

(By the way, the magnetic field in normal CT operation is confined to the toroidal core and the metal casing plays no part.)

Answer (score 0):

A single conductor generates a circumferential magnetic field around it.

If a single conductor is looped through a magnetic core, then this magnetic field will induce flux in the core. As the first wire links the core, this will look like a series inductance to the current in the wire.

If a further wire is now looped through the magnetic core, and short-circuited, the emf generated in the loop will cause a current to flow in this second wire, which will tend to reduce the inductance seen by the first wire.

This is the basis of a current transformer. In practice, the second loop is replaced by a large number of turns, 1000 is a popular figure, which reduces the current flowing in the secondary by the same factor. It also allows the secondary to be 'short-circuited' by a much higher value resistor, 50 ohms is a popular choice so the secondary can be measured with a normal oscilloscope.

If there is a further loop of conductor around the core, the secondary current will divide between the loops, compromising the gain accuracy of the intended output. If a conductive tape is placed over the secondary for electrostatic shielding, it will be insulated from itself (in a professionally made current transformer at least) so that it does not form a complete conductive turn through the magnetic core, so that even though an emf is generated across the facing edges, no current flows through it.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten a lot of comments and answers on this question. Thank you so much. I've read all of these and I tried to summarize them. I posted my own summary here, so if there is a need to correct it, please give me some comments.

CT (Current Transformer) typically has a metal case so you might wonder how it works at a high-frequency current. The primary conductor carrying the high-frequency current plays as an EM (Electromagnetic) wave antenna so B-field (magnetic field) becomes a part of the EM wave. In order for CT to work, the B-field must reach the coil (secondary winding in CT diagram) of CT. But the metal case which is much thicker than the skin depth at this high frequency will reflect the EM wave so it appears that the B-field doesn't touch the coil!

**If the metal case has no opening, then, yes, there is no way for CT to work at high frequency. However, if the metal case has the opening, the situation changes.** Think about toroidal CT which metal case is split into two equal pieces (the plane of splitting is the plane of the largest circumference of CT) and the separation between the pieces is fairly small. The EMF (Electromotive force) E-field, which is a dual to B-field in Maxwell-Faraday equation, around the surface of the metal case induces the current running the case surface in the plane of the primary conductor and radial vector from it. This current flows into the opening, running the inner surface of the case, and returns to the outer surface, to form a closed loop. The current on the inner surface is equal in magnitude but opposite in direction to the current on the outer surface. The B-field induced by the inner surface current has the same direction to the B-field outside. The field magnitude may also be the same (exact confirmation of this requires rigorous thinking of applying the Maxwell-Faraday and Maxwell-Ampere equation on both sides). **As a result, the B-field from the primary conductor with high-frequency current reaches the coil of the CT via induced current on the metal case which flows into the inner surface of the case through its opening, so CT works.**